# sequelizejs join table with additional attributes not working

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to implement a Sequelize join table with additional attributes, using an predefined model. However, the moment I associated it and sync it, it does not add the additional attributes into the association table as specified in Sequelize doc.

In mysql database, two tables are created instead of one: PartsPurchaseOrders and PurchaseOrderParts. I don't know how to get it working.

Please help me with this, Thanks!

```
var registry  = require('../models');

module.exports.model = function(sequelize, Sequelize) {
  return sequelize.define('PurchaseOrderParts', {
    recieved: {
      type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: false
    },
    recievedAt: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE, 
      defaultValue: null
    },
    quantity: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: 0,
      validate: {min: 0}
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      // this is where you add class methods
    },
    instanceMethods: {
      // this is where you add instance methods
    }
  });
};

module.exports.associations = function() {
  var PurchaseOrder = registry["PurchaseOrder"];
  var Part = registry["Part"];
  var PurchaseOrderParts = registry["PurchaseOrderParts"];

  Part.hasMany(PurchaseOrder, {through: PurchaseOrderParts});
  PurchaseOrder.hasMany(Part, {through: PurchaseOrderParts});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Through is a very recent a change, merging several different ways of specifying attributes of the join model. Before it was called joinTableModel

Could you try with the newest version from npm / master branch from github?

Answer (score 0):

I've played around with sequelize and had the same problem.

I've got two tables:

- List
- Items

They have a many-to-many relationship and I want to add a **quantity** to the x-table. The solution was, to define my own ListItem model and do the association like the following:

```
Item.hasMany(List, { joinTableModel: ListItem, useJunctionTable: false });
List.hasMany(Item, { joinTableModel: ListItem, useJunctionTable: false });
```

Tested with sqlite and the tables were created as expected. Adding Lists and Items work too, but don't know how to add the quantity value while adding the Items to the List or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `hasMany`, use `BelongsToMany`.

```js
Part.BelongsToMany(PurchaseOrder, {through: PurchaseOrderParts});
PurchaseOrder.BelongsToMany(Part, {through: PurchaseOrderParts});
```

Answer (score 0):

Came little much late, but for everyone who's looking at this:

You should check if your aditional attributes are nulleable.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).